# What is the "-C-" block in this example?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a the following image of a SIMULINK example (I can't click into the model):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqeOO.png]

But what is the "-C-" block (the PV0 one which is an input to the integrator block)?

I think its a constant, but don't know what should have inside it.

Answer (score 1):

It's surely a "Constant" block providing the initial state for the integrator. The [reference page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/integrator.html) for the integrator block describes how that 2nd input is used.

Comment: i would add that the constant block displays -C- on its mask when the name of the said constant doesn't fit the size of the block. Double click the block to see the constant, resize the block to properly display the constant name

Comment: @Edric I [tried](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/1431583/image.png) set it as Constant but get some error, I think it should be a matrix.
also this is the full [example](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/1431578/image.png)
thanks for helping!

Comment: @Ferro Luca sadly it is a PowerPoint file I cant "Double click" it lol

Comment: I'd try setting the constant to the value `ones(2,3)` which should create a 2x3 array of ones.